# URLs of facebook photos retrieved using access tokens are permanent or temporary

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to my web application facebook-page owners and facebook-users can keep their facebook photos in their profile gallery. So they would login in my facebook app and provide required access while configuring their profile in my web application. The web application will retrieve and enlist all photos through graph api, the user is required to select among them for keeping it in their gallery. I don't want to take any burden of storing those photos in my database so I would just store the URLs received. Further when other users of my web application views that person's profile or gallery, he/she will find those selected photos.

So are these URLs of photos retrieved through access tokens permanent? Will they work if the access token expires or user removes my facebook app from his/her facebook account in future or any other such activity? Or these photo URLs are permanent until the user disable or deactivate his/her facebook account?

Comment: If you are talking about CDN urls they are highly temporary

Comment: I will be using Faceboook Javascript SDK. I am not sure what type of urls will facebook provide in response whenever I send GET request. The users in my web application won't frequently keep updating gallery. They have various other tasks to perform as a routine. Once they are done with their gallery they won't bother about it for long time. So how could I have permanent urls which I would be storing in database?